# How do I want implement multiple user account login and switching in Firebase Authentication?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

In Gmail Android app, you can swipe on a user account view to switch to another account.

I use Firebase Authentication in my application.
How can such multiple login account and switching be implemented?

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between accounts when you are using GMail because all those accouns are GMail accounts. If you want to have the same behaviour, then you don't need to implement just simple Firebase authentication with user and password you need to implement: [Google Sign-In Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).